# Count the number of variable combinations in a logfile using perl

Tags: perl, logging, pattern-matching, subroutine

I have this logfile

```
 New connection: 141.8.83.213:64400 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: e696835c]
    2016-04-29 21:13:59+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test123] failed
    2016-04-29 21:14:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test1234] failed
    2016-04-29 21:14:13+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test123] failed
```

I want to output to file a result like this:

```
Port,Status,Occurrences
64400,failed,2
64400,failed,1
```

The "Occurrences" variable will represent the number of times a combination of login details[username and password] that have been recorded in the file. `User1 test123` can be seen recorded two times from the same IP. How can I do this? I have two while loops at the moment and a subroutine being called inside the first while loop like so:

**Subroutine**

```
sub counter(){

        $result = 0;
        #open(FILE2, $cowrie) or die "Can't open '$cowrie': $!";
        while(my $otherlines = <LOG2>){

                if($otherlines =~ /login attempt/){
                        ($user, $password) = (split /[\s:\[\]\/]+/, $otherlines)[-3,-2];
                        if($_[1] =~ /$user/ && $_[2] =~ /$password/){
                                $result++;
                        }#if ip matches i think i have to do this with split

                        #print "TEST\n";
                }
        #print "Combo $_[0] and $_[1]\n";

        }
        #print "$result";
        return $result;
}
```

**Main method**

```
sub cowrieExtractor(){

        open(FILE2, $cowrie) or die "Can't open '$cowrie': $!";

        open(LOG2, $path2) or die "Can't open '$path2': $!";

        $seperator = chr(42);
        #To output user and password of login attempt, set $ip variable to the contents of array at that x position of new
        #connection to match the ip of the login attempt
        print FILE2 "SourcePort"."$seperator".
        "Status"."$seperator"."Occurences"."$seperator"."Malicious"."\n";

        $ip = "";
        $port = "";
        $usr = "";
        $pass = "";
        $status = "";
        $frequency = 0;

        #Given this is a user/pass attempt honeypot logger, I will use a wide character to reduce the possibility of stopping
        #the WEKA CSV loader from functioning by using smileyface as seperators.


        while(my $lines = <LOG2>){

                if($lines =~ /New connection/){

                ($ip, $port) = (split /[\[\]\s:()]+/, $lines)[7,8];

                }
                if($lines =~ /login attempt/){#and the ip of the new connection
if($lines =~ /$ip/){
                ($usr, $pass, $status) = (split /[\s:\[\]\/]+/, $lines)[-3,-2,-1];

                        $frequency = counter($ip, $usr, $pass);

                        #print $frequency;
                        if($ip && $port && $usr && $pass && $status ne ""){
                                print FILE2 join "$seperator",($port, $status, $frequency, $end);
                                print FILE2 "\n";
                        }
                }


                }
        }


}
```

Right now in output under `Occurrences` in output I am getting a `0` and when I tested it appears to be coming from what I initialize the variable `$result` in the subroutine. i.e. 0; meaning that the if statement inside the subroutine is not working properly. Any help?

Comment: You should never use prototypes on Perl subroutines. They don't do what you think they do. Just `sub counter { ... }` and `sub cowrieExtractor { ... }` is correct

Comment: *"without involving hashes if possible"* hashes are exactly the right tool for this. Why do you want to avoid them?

Comment: I can't help but ask: why "_without involving hashes_"?  And what does that mean -- a solution which wouldn't use a hash data type at all?  (What exactly are your requirements?)

Comment: I'm puzzled that your output example shows the *status* and *port* fields but no user information, yet you say you want to group the information only by user. That means there will be a mixture of statuses and ports for each count and the data cannot be summarised like this

Comment: Sorry about the not involve hashes part. I just did some research and hashes are perfect for this I just do not know how to use them well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic way to get expected output. Questions about the context (purpose) remain.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'logfile.txt';
open my $fh_in, '<', $file;

# Assemble results for required output in data structure:
# %rept = { $port => { $usr => { $status => $freq } };

my %rept;
my ($ip, $port);

while (my $line = <$fh_in>) 
{
    if ($line =~ /New connection/) {
        ($ip, $port) = $line =~ /New connection:\s+([^:]+):(\d+)/;
        next;
    }   

    my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/login\ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x;
    if ($usr and $status) {
        $rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++;
    }   
    else { warn "Line with an unexpected format:\n$line" }
}

# use Data::Dumper;
# print Dumper \%rept;

print "Port,Status,Occurences\n";
foreach my $port (sort keys %rept) {
    foreach my $usr (sort keys %{$rept{$port}}) {
        foreach my $stat ( sort keys %{$rept{$port}{$usr}} ) { 
            print "$port,$stat,$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat}\n"; 
        }   
    }   

}
```

With your input copied into a file `logfile.txt` this prints

```
Port,Status,Occurences
64400,failed,2
64400,failed,1
```

I take the whole `user1/test123` (etc) to identify the user. This can be changed in the regex as needed.
Note that this will not allow you to query or organize data very differently, it mostly pulls what is needed for the required output.  Please let me know if explanations are needed.

---

*An introductory explanation of the nested hash used above*

First, I strongly recommend a good reading of some of the many materials available.
A good start is surely the standard tutorial on [Perl 
references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), as well as a cookbook of sorts 
on [Perl data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

The hash used to collect data has keys which are port numbers, and each of them has
for its value a *hash reference* (or, rather, an *anonymous hash*).  Each of these 
hashes has keys which are users, which for their values have, again, hash references.
The keys for these are the possible values of status, so there are two keys (failed 
and succeded).  Their values are frequencies.  This kind of 'nesting' is a *complex 
data structure*.  There is another important thing.  The first time the statement
`$rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++` is seen the whole hierarchy is created.  So the key 
`$port` did not need to exist beforehand.  Importantly, this *auto vivification* 
happens even if a structure is merely queried for values (unless it actually exists
already).

After the first iteration, the hash is

```
%rept = { '64400' => { 'user1/test123' => { 'failed' => 1 } } }
```

In the second iteration the same port is seen but a new user, so new data is added to the second-level anonymous hash. The key with the new user is created, with its value being a (new) anonymous hash, with `status => count`. The whole hash is:

```
%rept = { 
    '64400' => { 
        'user1/test123'  => { 'failed' => 1 },
        'user1/test1234' => { 'failed' => 1 },
    } 
}
```

In the next iteration the same port is seen and one of already existing users, and
as it happens with the status (failed) which also exists.  Thus the count for that
status is incremented.

The whole strucure can handily be seen using, for example, the 
[Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.154/Dumper.pm) package.
The commented out lines in the code above would produce

```
$VAR1 = {
    '64400' => {
        'user1/test123' => {
                                'failed' => 2
                           },
        'user1/test1234' => {
                                'failed' => 1
                            }
                }
        };
```

As we keep processing lines new keys are added as needed (ports, users, status) with the full hierarchy down to the count (of 1 the first time), or, if an existing is encountered, its count is incremented. The generated data structure can be traversed and used as seen in the code, for example. Please also see the plentiful documentation for more on that.

Comment: this worked really well thankyou. What if I want to increment the occurrence also based on how many times an IP X.X.X.X used the same combination of pass/usr attempts? So it will be like an `||` statement somehow to either increment if there are multiple ports using the same combo or an IP using same combo?

Comment: Also how does  `my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/login\ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x;` work so that I can extract the IP as well and make the `or` condition before incrementing?

Comment: @firepro20  I will deal with this as soon as I can, and add an explanation.  However, given your next post, this may help immediately.  The `$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat}` (from last line of print) means the following: in the hash `%rept`, for port number `$port` and for user `$usr` and for status `$stat` (failed or succeded), the frequency is precisely that, `$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat}`.  So this is the frequency of 'failed' or 'succeded' for user `$usr` at port `$port`.  Then the print goes through all possibilities, giving frequencies at each port for each user for each status.  Does this help?

Comment: @firepro20  I've added an explanation of sorts.  I'll edit tomorrow since I am sure that it can be improved.  But _please_ do read up on this from better sources, for example the first one linked.  It will pay off handily if you continue using Perl.  Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: So following your explanation I need to either create a new hash say %test and go where there is this line of code

`my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/login\ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x;
`

(p.s How can I get the IP from that match regex?)

Extract the IP from the login attempt line and say `if ($ip){%test($ip)++} `  then go to the printing part and do after all the `foreach` the following `foreach my $ip(sort keys %($test($ip)))` and `print "$port,$stat,$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat}, $test{$ip}\n";` Correct?

Comment: I want to get this line `my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/login\ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x;
    if ($usr and $status) {
        $rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++;
    }
    else { warn "Line with an unexpected format:\n$line" }
`
then get the IP from the first line of code, problem is I do not undertand exactly how you re assigning the variables from that regex. Do an elseif to increment another hash like `$test{$ip}++` and some how print something like `Port,Status,OccurrencesonSrcPort, OccurrencesonIP`
would be like `64400,failed,2,3` as the ip is seen three times in login attempt

Comment: @firepro20  Yes, you would make another hash, for example. OK, now I understand what you mean, I will add that -- unless you beat me to it.  (I did add IP counting for your other post already.) It looks like I should add some regex explanation as well, correct?

Comment: Yes please. The new hash almost works but it print all entries 3 times so its not perfect. Could you please clarify. Thanks in advance for all the support given so far. Truly appreciate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110864/discussion-between-firepro20-and-zdim).