# Counting the frequency of seperate IP entries PERL

Tags: perl, loops, design-patterns, matching

I have the following logfile and I want to output the frequency of distinct IPs that are in the file:

```
2016-04-29 15:08:47+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:34826 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: c9d2f438]
2016-04-29 15:08:48+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,10,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/password] succeeded
2016-04-29 15:08:56+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:51999 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 57235446]
2016-04-29 15:08:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,11,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/toor] failed
2016-04-29 15:08:57+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:46466 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 03862a50]
2016-04-29 15:09:00+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,12,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/unix] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:02+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:56756 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 9b8cd979]
2016-04-29 15:09:03+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,13,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/test123] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:04+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:50215 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 2e68b87e]
2016-04-29 15:09:07+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,14,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/toor123] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:08+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:58407 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: f8d1d9ae]
2016-04-29 15:09:12+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,15,159.122.123.181] login attempt [shell/shell] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:13+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:48225 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 091fcb7e]
2016-04-29 15:09:17+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,16,159.122.123.181] login attempt [admin/root] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:18+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:35815 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 49ad22eb]
2016-04-29 15:09:20+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,17,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/admin] succeeded
2016-04-29 15:09:27+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:58114 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: e214b2c4]
2016-04-29 15:09:28+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,18,159.122.123.181] login attempt [admin/admin] succeeded
2016-04-29 15:09:35+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:45180 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 61c00c6c]
2016-04-29 15:09:36+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,19,159.122.123.181] login attempt [guest/guest123] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:38+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:37525 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: d19434e3]
2016-04-29 15:09:42+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,20,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/webmaster] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:43+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:36967 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: de78048a]
2016-04-29 15:09:44+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,21,159.122.123.181] login attempt [admin/administrator] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:45+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:56465 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 58eeea98]
2016-04-29 15:09:47+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,22,159.122.123.181] login attempt [mysql/mysql] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:51145 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 905c8982]
2016-04-29 15:09:50+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,23,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/shell] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:51+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:54406 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: c6f21bfe]
2016-04-29 15:09:53+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,24,159.122.123.181] login attempt [guest/guest] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:55+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:58764 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 167d51cf]
2016-04-29 15:09:56+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,25,159.122.123.181] login attempt [root/linux] failed
2016-04-29 15:09:58+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 159.122.123.181:57158 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: daa3fc72]
2016-04-29 15:10:01+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,26,159.122.123.181] login attempt [unix/unix] failed
2016-04-29 15:15:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:42359 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 930332a7]
2016-04-29 15:15:50+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,27,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 15:56:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:46055 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 3b8d22b5]
2016-04-29 15:56:49+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 16:11:14+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 52.28.89.99:53059 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: a6c0fac1]
2016-04-29 16:17:42+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 13.92.114.157:1032 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: d33e1566]
2016-04-29 19:07:10+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:45178 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: fafec37d]
2016-04-29 19:07:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,0,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 19:42:58+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:56925 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: 539960a3]
2016-04-29 19:42:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,1,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 20:39:03+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:54138 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: b9f550df]
2016-04-29 20:39:03+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,2,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 21:13:41+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 141.8.83.213:64400 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: e696835c]
2016-04-29 21:13:59+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test123] failed
2016-04-29 21:14:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test1234] failed
2016-04-29 21:14:13+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test123] failed
```

This is the perl script I have so far, kindly provided by @zdim [in a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964981/count-the-number-of-variable-combinations-in-a-logfile-using-perl/36965385#36965385) and tweaked a bit as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = "/home/tsec/prototype/logs/extractedlogs/cowrieresult.log";
open (LOG, $file);

# Assemble results for required output in data structure:
# %rept = { $port => { $usr => { $status => $freq } };
my $frequency = 0;
my %rept;
my ($ip, $port);

while (my $line = <LOG>)
{
    if ($line =~ /New connection/) {
        ($ip, $port) = $line =~ /New connection:\s+([^:]+):(\d+)/;
        next;
    }

    my ($usr, $status) =  $line =~ m/login\ attempt \s+ \[ ( [^\]]+ ) \] \s+ (\w+)/x;
    if ($usr and $status) {
        $rept{$port}{$usr}{$status}++;
    }
    else { warn "Line with an unexpected format:\n$line" }


}

close(LOG);
open (LOG, $file);

while (my $line = <LOG>){
        if($line =~ /login attempt/){

        #split string, get the ip and match it with original $ip
        my ($testip) = (split /[\s,:\[\]\/]+/, $line)[-6];
        #print "$testip\n";
        #this two lines above print ips from login attempt line.
        if($testip =~ /$ip/){
                $frequency++;
        }
        else {
                # stop frequency counter and start another one?
                print "$frequency\n";
                $frequency = 0;
        }

        }
}
print "$frequency\n";
close(LOG);
```

Right now the output is as follows, which is working for the last three entries in the log file as the IP is seen 3 times in the end:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
3
```

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate all your help. Thankyou

Comment: What is the expected output for this sample data?

Comment: Is the purpose of your second `while` solely to print out the frequencies? You have that in the hash from my previous post, correctly for this input as well. In the last line of those nested `foreach` where the results are printed out you can print only the frequencies: `print "$rept{$port}{$usr}{$stat}\n"`.  Then you don't need the second `while`.  (I am due to write an explanation on that post, and will do that.)  Does this answer this question? If not please clarify.

Comment: Yes the sole purpose is to print the frequencies **based on IP** unlike the other post which is based on source port. I want to know how hash work so I'm waiting on your explanation on the previous post. Thankyou. If you see my comment on the other post, if it is possible I would also like to count the number of occurrences of the IP per se so that I have the port, status, occurence of usr pass combo passed on IP and no of occurence of the IP on its own

Comment: @zdim for now I'm going to sleep cause its 1am over here. I'll respond to any comments tomorrow. Thankyou for your continuous help

Comment: So you want the frequency for each IP, on all ports and for all users -- one line per IP?  How about status, should that be distinguished? Can you add the expected output?

Comment: `Port, Status, AttemptsonPort, AttemptsonIP`

Where attempts on port is what your script already does. Attempts on IP should give how many times that IP has occurred while reading the file. So like `159.122.123.181` is seen 14 times for instance or `141.8.83.213` 3 times

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do in your perl script, it seems a  bit confused. I was going to try and debug it but as I can't quite make out what your goal is, its hard to debug. If you could clarify why you have 2 while loops and what you are expecting each loop to do and to output, someone might be able to give you more feedback. in the mean time, you could always use standard command line tools to get your answer if you are in a hurry:

```
grep 'login attempt' logfile.txt | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

will output something like:

```
      3 141.8.83.213
      5 89.248.167.131
     17 159.122.123.181
```

credit to @gilles-quenot for the regex for extracting IP addresses using grep

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928624/386557